# Почему не удается найти искомое по тегу и классу(селектору) с помощью BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

```py
import requests,bs4

def getAmazonPrice(url):
    res = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=macbook&oq=macbook&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l7.1428j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8") 
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    x = soup.find_all("div", class_="r4awE")
    print(x)
```

Comment: Google возможно защищает контент от парсинга выдавая сгенерированные имена классов и прочего, может быть в контексте сессии работы bs4 элементов такого класса нет?

Comment: Это сгенерированный класс. При каждом запросе странницы названия классов меняются (товарищ из предыдущего комента прав). Используй XPath без классов (хотя, например, у Твиттера еще и XPath не работают, так как вложенность элементов тоже меняется). Еще есть вариант, что изначально страница вообще пустая и наполняется динамически исключительно средствами js

Comment: Присоединюсь к двум предыдущим участникам, добавлю лишь совет. Попробуйте использовать `selenium` для прогружаемых страниц.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите найти? Может проще не по классу искать, раз он переменный.